# Ordenar de mayor a menor en javascript

Tags: javascript

```
let orderbyDefault = [-8,-4,-3,-4,-2,2,8,7,9];
```

```js
let orderbyDefault = [-8,-4,-3,-4,-2,2,8,7,9]
console.log(orderbyDefault.sort());
```

Pero el resultado de salida que busco es [2,7,8,9,-2,-3,-4,-4,-8]
Me puede ayudar a resolver.

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(orderbyDefault.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

Si los valores son string usa

```
orderbyDefault.reverse();
```

Comment: Mil gracias, son numeros, pero la salida que me sale es [-8, -4, -4, -3, -2, 2, 7, 8, 9] pero en realidad espero como resultado esto [2,7,8,9,-2,-3,-4,-4,-8]

Comment: Pues entonces donde pone a-b pon b-a

Comment: Mil Gracias @Juan Enrique García Sancho